# Can not run the whole T-SQL query but in parts I can

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Guy's I'm having issues with this query of mine. I have done what i can and now it's coming towards the end. If i run the 2 separate it works perfectly but once i select the whole thing to run as on piece it give me an error about the temp table already existing even though I check if the Temp table exists and drop it at the end and the beginning of each "batch" i would call it.

I don't really know what piece of the query to post so I'm just going to post the whole thing. If Someone can give me insight of why it is doing this and other tips that you might see me doing wrong.

```
Use test
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMP

    IF OBJECT_ID('MetricsServerAudit') IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN 
            CREATE TABLE  #TEMP ([TIME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[DATE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_LOGIN] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[MODEL_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,  [SCORECARD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PERIOD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION_TYPE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PREVIOUS_VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[UNIT] nvarchar(max) NULL)

                    BULK INSERT #TEMP FROM 'C:\QPR_Logs\Audit\MetricsServerAudit.txt'
                    WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '\r', FIRSTROW = 2, KEEPNULLS)

                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [DATE]= REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DATE],103),'/' ,'-') 
                    ALTER TABLE #TEMP ALTER COLUMN [DATE] DATE
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = '12:00:00' Where [TIME] = ''
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([TIME], CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = REPLACE([TIME], '/', ':')
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = left([TIME], 8)
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [DATE] = '2015-01-01' Where [DATE] is null


                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MetricsServerAudit]([DateStamp],[TIME],[DATE],[USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[MODEL_NAME],[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER],[SCORECARD_NAME],[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER],[ELEMENT_NAME],[SERIES_IDENTIFIER],[SERIES_NAME],[PERIOD_NAME],[ACTION_TYPE],[ACTION],[PREVIOUS_VALUE],[VALUE],[UNIT])
                    SELECT CONCAT([DATE],'', [TIME]) AS [DateStamp], [TIME],[DATE],[USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[MODEL_NAME],[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER],[SCORECARD_NAME],[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER],[ELEMENT_NAME],[SERIES_IDENTIFIER],[SERIES_NAME],[PERIOD_NAME],[ACTION_TYPE],[ACTION],[PREVIOUS_VALUE],[VALUE],[UNIT]
                    FROM #TEMP
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT [TIME] FROM [dbo].[MetricsServerAudit] WHERE [TIME] = [TIME])
                    DROP TABLE #TEMP
        END

Else --SEPERATOR 
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMP

    IF OBJECT_ID('MetricsServerAudit') IS NULL
        BEGIN 
            CREATE TABLE  MetricsServerAudit ([DateStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL, [TIME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[DATE] date NULL,[USER_LOGIN] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[MODEL_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SCORECARD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PERIOD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION_TYPE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PREVIOUS_VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[UNIT] nvarchar(max) NULL)
        END
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NULL
                BEGIN
                    CREATE TABLE  #TEMP ([TIME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[DATE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_LOGIN] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[MODEL_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,  [SCORECARD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PERIOD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION_TYPE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PREVIOUS_VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[UNIT] nvarchar(max) NULL)

                    BULK INSERT #TEMP FROM 'C:\QPR_Logs\Audit\MetricsServerAudit.txt'
                    WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '\r', FIRSTROW = 2, KEEPNULLS)

                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [DATE]= REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DATE],103),'/' ,'-') 
                    ALTER TABLE #TEMP ALTER COLUMN [DATE] DATE
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = '12:00:00' Where [TIME] = ''
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([TIME], CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = REPLACE([TIME], '/', ':')
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = left([TIME], 8)
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [DATE] = '2015-01-01' Where [DATE] is null                 


                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MetricsServerAudit]([TIME],[DATE],[USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[MODEL_NAME],[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER],[SCORECARD_NAME],[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER],[ELEMENT_NAME],[SERIES_IDENTIFIER],[SERIES_NAME],[PERIOD_NAME],[ACTION_TYPE],[ACTION],[PREVIOUS_VALUE],[VALUE],[UNIT])
                    SELECT [TIME],[DATE],[USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[MODEL_NAME],[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER],[SCORECARD_NAME],[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER],[ELEMENT_NAME],[SERIES_IDENTIFIER],[SERIES_NAME],[PERIOD_NAME],[ACTION_TYPE],[ACTION],[PREVIOUS_VALUE],[VALUE],[UNIT]
                    FROM #TEMP
                    DROP TABLE #TEMP

                    UPDATE [dbo].[MetricsServerAudit] SET [DateStamp] = CONCAT([DATE],'', [TIME])
                    UPDATE [dbo].[MetricsServerAudit] SET [DateStamp] = REPLACE([DateStamp], '/', ':')
                    UPDATE [dbo].[MetricsServerAudit] SET [DateStamp] = CONVERT(datetime,(SUBSTRING([DateStamp],1,10)+' '+SUBSTRING([DateStamp],11,15)))
                    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetricsServerAudit] ALTER COLUMN [DateStamp] DATETIME
                END
```

By the else is the separator that i talk of so everything above it is "Batch1",
and everything below it is "Batch2"

The error I get is :

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
There is already an object named '#TEMP' in the database.
```

Comment: [tag:mysql] is a completely different database product. Unless your question in some way involves it (it's not apparent from a quick read), please remove that tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ELSE` is not a batch separator, and any temporary tables you use and don't drop will throw this error.

Unless you've specifically changed the batch separator, you should use `GO` in-between your batches. That way any temporary tables will be dropped between batch separation.

Comment: Well what i mean with separator is that if I select everything above that point or select everything below that point and execute it it works. but as a whole piece it doesnt

Comment: Precisely my point. T-SQL doesn't follow the logical flow that you're expecting. You can declare a temporary table within an `IF` block and even if the `IF` isn't reached, the temporary table is still reserved and created in tempdb. You're much better off separating the batches with the **batch separator**. It was specifically introduced for this reason.

Comment: Thank you John I have learnt something new today! I really appreciate it! I'm still new to this all and still have a long way to go but thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I've only got 4 years experience myself, and I never stop learning new things every day ;)

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL is declarative, when you execute the SQL the first thing the optimiser does is look at your batch of SQL and then create an execution plan (that is before anything actually executes), so, to the optimiser you do indeed have two CREATE TABLE #TEMP which is invalid. You can't even use dynamic SQL here because the scope of the # table is the EXEC('') statement - you could use a global temporary table with EXEC( ). That, or simply use two different table names.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the T-SQL parser is remarkably simplistic which can lead to surprising results. Notably, a lot of things don't follow any flow control. E.g.

```
IF 1 = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @a int
END
SET @a = 1
```

Executes without error - because a variable is valid from the point of *declaration* until the end of the batch - the declarations don't have to be "reached".

Similarly, once a temp table has been introduced, it's definition is valid until the end of the batch.

Comment: Although this is a valid point, and one I made in the comments on my answer. It doesn't directly answer his question, but still I'm not sure why it's down voted.

Comment: @JohnBell - yeah, I was going for a general "don't bring your expectations from other languages to T-SQL" type answer, and went with the example that I think best demonstrates this.

Comment: When I started using T-SQL, I threw up all my logic in the waste paper bin. Every now and then I go home at the end of the day and my verbal sentences are so garbled, Yoda would find me hard to understand.